# How to deal with index signature for a simple object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert the returned number status to a string in the UI like so:

```
{statuses[job.status]}

const statuses = {
  1: "Processing",
  2: "Done",
  3: "Aborted",
  4: "Queued",
}
```

But getting this message:

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type
> '{ 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; 4: string; }'

I've tried adding an interface but still getting the same issue

```
interface IStatus {
  1: string;
  2: string;
  3: string;
  4: string;
}

const statuses = {
  1: "Processing",
  2: "Done",
  3: "Aborted",
  4: "Queued",
} as IStatus;
```

I've searched for ways around this, but can't seem to get it working in my instance.

Comment: What is `job`? If the status must be one of the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, the solution may be to restrict the type of `job.status` so that it is `1 | 2 | 3 | 4`. Or more naturally, use an enum type for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
const statuses: Record<number, string> = {
  1: "Processing",
  2: "Done",
  3: "Aborted",
  4: "Queued",
  // ...
}
```

Refer: [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

---

You can also use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) like this:

```
{statuses[job.status as keyof statuses]}
```

---

If you just have `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` as keys, then it is better to just type your `job.status` as `1 | 2 | 3 | 4` (same as `keyof statuses`). `Record<number, string>` will accept all numbers as key, which may result in weaker type checking. If you are not getting `job` from some external source, you can try using [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add [Index Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/glossary#index-signatures) to your interface

```
interface IStatus {
    [key: number]: string,
    1: string;
    2: string;
    3: string;
    4: string;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECmEBcMCSBlKiKMAvDAN4BQMMAjFgEQAKATiMOhAJZgDm9ANFRgAmBgBFwqAUIDMDAIIAjEMyioAJtOoAWBgEUkqQ5sEBfChVCRYAKxCKIJGAG1K1amHgBbVFgDkAHLwAG6eUAAWfoLucATImLQUpoJu7p4%20-gBC4fBIUULUCPFY2kkAugDcFNxqzABm8Ow4%20ISOqc4A1qgAnlhgSF6KqMxlWNDM3DzRtGNQE7xV1KKx8zyLMHIrk%20u6WwtJFnYOAHR1KgCijeEAFEckAHzkluAQIAA2qMdvIDzXRSjoZxHY7-CBlACUVVMkKAA)